# Add p-values in corrplot matrix

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, r-corrplot, significance

I calculated the Spearman correlation between two matrices and I'm plotting the r values using `corrplot`. How can I plot only the significant correlations (so only those correlations having p value lower than 0.00 and delete those having higher p value, even if are strong correlations - high value of r). I generated the correlation matrix using `corr.test` in `psych` package, so I already have the p values in `cor.matrix$p`

This is the code I'm using:

```
library(corrplot)
library(psych)
corr.test(mydata_t1, mydata_t2, method="spearman")
M <- corrplot(cor.matrix$r, method="square",type="lower",col=col1(100),is.corr=T,mar=c(1,1,1,1),tl.cex=0.5)
```

How can I modify it to plot only significant corelations?

Comment: What do you want to do with the cells where correlations are greater than zero?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well... I want to plot positive and negative correlations, with a p value < 0.05. If p>0.05, I want a white cell...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the examples of corrplot. do `?corrplot`. It has options for doing what you want.
You can plot the p-values on the graph itself, which I think is better than putting stars, 
as people not familiar with that terminology have one more thing to look up.
to put p-values on graph do this `corrplot(cor.matrix$r, p.mat = cor.matrix$p, insig = "p-value")` where cor.matrix is object holding the result of cor.test.
The `insig` option can put:

- p-values (as shown above)
- blank out insignificant correlations with corrplot(cor.matrix$r, p.mat = cor.matrix$p, insig = "blank")`
- Cross out (put a X on) insignificant correlations) with option `corrplot(cor.matrix$r, p.mat = cor.matrix$p, insig = "pch")` (DEFAULT)
- Do nothing with to the plot, with `corrplot(cor.matrix$r, p.mat = cor.matrix$p, insig = "n")`

If you do want stars, p-value on the correlation matrix plot - take a look at this thread [Correlation Corrplot Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012529/correlation-corrplot-configuration)

Though I have to say I really like [@sven hohenstein's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627235/sven-hohenstein) elegant subset solution.

Answer (score 4):

Create a copy of `cor.mat` and replace the corresponding correlation coefficients with zero:

```
cor.matrix2 <- cor.matrix

# find cells with p-values > 0.05 and replace corresponding
# correlations coefficients with zero
cor.matrix2$r[cor.matrix2$p > 0.05] <- 0

# use this matrix for corrplot
M <- corrplot(cor.matrix2$r, method="square",type="lower",col=col1(100),
              is.corr=T,mar=c(1,1,1,1),tl.cex=0.5)
```

The replaced values will appear as a white cell.

Comment: And if I want to plot all the corelations, but add a star in the cells with a significant correlation?

Comment: @FrancescadeFilippis This another problem. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is similar to what [`subset`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html) does:

> Return subsets of vectors, matrices or data frames which meet
>   conditions.

So you can do:

```
cor.matrix <- subset(cor.matrix, p<0.00)
P <- corrplot(cor.matrix$r, method="square",type="lower",col=col1(100),is.corr=T,mar=c(1,1,1,1),tl.cex=0.5)
```

Comment: Maybe now works (I edited the question)but the other two answers are better and taking into account the package functionalities.