# Pairwise smoothScatter with correlation on upper diagonal in R

Tags: r, plot

[image]

Can someone explain to me how to correctly write the `panel.cor` function to get the labels for pairwise correlations of the columns of the matrix (my_matrix) supplied to the `pairs` function?

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
pairs(my_matrix,
      upper.panel = panel.cor, 
      panel = function(...) smoothScatter(..., nbin=64,
                                            nrpoints = 0,  
                                            add = TRUE), gap = 0.2, ylim = c(-5,5), xlim=c(-5,5)
      )   

panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=3, prefix="",  ...) {
  r <- cor(x,y)
}
```

The function supplied to the `panel` argument is from the examples section of the `smoothScatter` help page.

Comment: Check out the `panel.shadeNtext` function from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19014110/5619526).

Comment: Thanks, that works!